# Find all numbers that are equal to the product of all their proper divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example:
$6$ has this property since proper divisors of $6$ are: $2$ and $3.

From this thread: [What does the product of all proper divisors equal to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24126/what-does-the-product-of-all-proper-divisors-equal-to)

My attempt was:
If $n = p_1^{a_1} \times p_2^{a_2} \times ... \times p_k^{a_k}$
Then $n = n^{\frac{\tau(n)}{2} - 1}$. Where $\tau(n) = (a_1 + 1) \times (a_2 + 1) \times ... \times (a_k + 1)$

So is it good enough to stop here, or we can express $n$ in a better formula?

Comment: You missed a factor 2 in the exponent from Arturo Magidin's answer to the earlier question.  This leads naturally to Sivaram Ambikasaran's answer to this one.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Opp! My bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n = n^{\tau(n)/2 - 1}$ implies $\tau(n)=4$ and so $n$ is a product of two primes or the cube of a prime.

Comment: Nice thought! Thanks for this clever hint.

Answer (score 4):

Any number of the form $n = p_1 \times p_2$ where $p_1,p_2$ are primes.

Comment: Ambikasaran: Thank you.

Comment: You've missed $n=p^3$.