# Tackling the following question regarding inequality for the product of divisors of a number $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been stuck with proving the following equality:
$$\prod_{d\mid n} d = n^{\nu(n)/2}$$
Where $\nu(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Here's how I've approached the problem so far:

The desired equation will be true $$\iff log(\prod_{d\mid n} d) = log(n^{\nu(n)/2})$$
$$\iff \sum_{d\mid n} log(d) = \frac{\nu(n)}{2} \cdot log(n)$$
We consider the PF of $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdot...\cdot p_k^{a_k}$, and thus $$\frac{\nu(n)}{2}\cdot log(n) = \frac{1}{2}\prod_{p\mid n}(a_i+1)\cdot \sum_{p_i\mid n} a_ilog(p_i)$$
We pair up each $(a_i+1)$ with its respective $a_ilog(p_i)$ term, ultimately getting the following
$$=\sum_{p_i\mid n} (a_i^2+a_i)log p_i$$

This feels so close to the final desired result, but I'm struggling to get the final desired result. I'm having trouble specifically understanding what all the possible terms $\sum_{d\mid n} log(d)$ look like.

No need for the final answer - just hints towards it/additional steps that I should be looking to take would be really helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $ \prod_{d|n} d= n^{\frac{\tau (n)}{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337022/how-to-prove-prod-dn-d-n-frac-tau-n2) - found using an [Approach0 seach](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cprod_%7Bd%5Cmid%20n%7Dd%3Dn%5E%7B%5Cnu(n)%2F2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Anumber%20divisors&p=1), which actually found [Product of all divisors](/q/534171) that was closed as a duplicate of this question's proposed duplicate.

Comment: Starting a title with "help" and using the word "question" in titles are unfortunately two highly effectively factors to predict the quality of the post. Please use a more discriptive and straightforward title.